# What models will you suggest to use in Industrial Anomaly Detection and Predictive analysis on live streamed data?

Tags: neural-networks, models, anomaly-detection

I have been working on industrial data, that is fed live, I want to explore a few models which might suit for this the best.

The data are [KPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performance_indicator) data from the manufacturing Industry.